# 'Pausar' e 'Retornar' AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Eu tenho um código na minha página que faz upload de arquivos.

Esses arquivos que são enviados, possuem campos específicos preenchidos(Ex: nome, telefone, email) e não é possível alterar esse tipo de documento. Se a pessoa deixa um campo em branco, irá ficar em branco. Entretanto eu preciso dessas informações.

O upload é enviado por jQuery para uma outra página PHP onde é feito todo o processo de leitura desse documento e salvamento no banco de dados e retorna um mensagem (sucess/ error).

Minha dúvida é, existe algum meio de, ao perceber o campo em branco no documento retornar a mensagem, abrir um popup, e a pessoa preencher um input, e retomar o AJAX de onde parou com a nova informação?

---

Obrigado, utilizo o seguinte código para exibição HTML:

```
<form id="upload" method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div id="drop">
      Arraste os arquivos ZIP aqui
      <br/>
      <a>Pesquisar...</a>
      <input type="file" name="upl" multiple />
   </div>
   <ul>
      <!-- The file uploads will be shown here -->
   </ul>
</form>

<!-- JavaScript Includes -->
<script src="assets/js/jquery.knob.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery File Upload Dependencies -->
<script src="assets/js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>

<!-- Our main JS file -->
<script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>
```

Junto com a biblioteca de [jQuery File Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)

---

'upload.php' para onde o FORM é enviado sem o recarregamento da página:

```
$allowed = array('zip');

if(isset($_FILES['upl']) && $_FILES['upl']['error'] == 0){

    $filename = $_FILES['upl']['name'];
    $source = $_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'];
    $type = $_FILES['upl']['type'];

    $name = explode('.', $filename);
    $target = 'uploads/extracted/' . $name[0] . '-' . time() . '/';
    $target2 = 'uploads/extracted/' . $name[0] . '-' . time();

    $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['upl']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if(!in_array(strtolower($extension), $allowed)){
        echo '{"status":"error"}';
        exit;
    }

    if(move_uploaded_file($source, 'uploads/'.$filename)){
        // INICIA CÓDIGO PARA SALVAR INFO NO DB
        // Solicita NANODicom
        require 'nanodicom/nanodicom.php';

        // Cria pasta caso não exista
        if(!is_dir($target)){
            mkdir($target, 0744);
        }

        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        $x = $zip->open('uploads/'.$filename);

        // Extrai arquivos
        if($x === true) {
            $zip->extractTo($target);
            $zip->close();
        } else {
            echo '{"status":"error"}';
            exit;
        }

        // Procura por arquivos DCM nas pastas      
        $ar = array();
        $studyID = array();
        $files = findDcm($target2);

        // INICIO da leitura dos DCM com NANODicom
        if($files === true){
            foreach ($ar as $file){
                try{
                    // 2) Load only given tags. It will stop once all given tags are found. Fastest!
                    $dicom = Nanodicom::factory($file, 'simple');
                    // Only a small subset of the dictionary entries were loaded
                    $dicom->parse()->profiler_diff('parse')."<br/>";

                    // Verifica se existe exames diferentes
                    if(!in_array($dicom->value(0x0020, 0x0010), $studyID) || !count($studyID)){
                        $studyID[] = $dicom->value(0x0020, 0x0010);

                        $exame = saveStudy($dicom, "uploads/$filename");

                        if(!$exame){
                            echo '{"status":"error"}';
                            exit;
                        }
                    }

                    unset($dicom);
                } catch (Nanodicom_Exception $e){
                    echo '{"status":"error"}';
                    exit;
                }
            }
        } else{
            echo '{"status":"error"}';
            exit;
        }
        // FIM da leitura dos DCM

        // Exclui pasta para ganhar espaço
        $result = delTree($target2);
        // FIM CÓDIGO PARA SALVAR INFO NO DB
        echo '{"status":"success"}';
        exit;
    } else{
        echo 'erro ao gravar arquivo.';
        echo '{"status":"error"}';
        exit;
    }
}

//echo 'erro arquivo: '.$_FILES['upl']['error'];
echo '{"status":"error"}';
exit;
```

A função findDcm() pesquisa pasta por pasta pelos arquivos com .dcm que é o tipo de arquivo que é enviado.

A função saveStudy() salva as variáveis no banco.

A verificação se existe o valor dentro do arquivo pode ser feito tanto aqui, como no saveStudy(), mas assim que verificar que um valor está em branco precisa retornar alguma mensagem com um campo input para o usuário preencher o valor que faltava.

Comment: Sim, chama-se a isso validação de inputs. Podes colocar o código do formulário que tens?

Comment: Editei o post para poder caber o código, entretanto acho que você não entendeu. A biblioteca de ler o documento que é enviado é em PHP, por isso preciso enviar o AJAX para saber os campos que estão faltando. E salvar no banco. Eu não tenho as informações antes de envia-lo

Comment: Ok, então queres que o PHP envie o pedido para o lado do cliente e "fique à espera da resposta" para continuar? mas como são enviados esses dados? não é no lado do cliente? tens acesso a esse código?

Comment: Este é todo o código. Os dados são enviados sem recarregar da página, todo o envio é feito pela biblioteca do File Upload, ele envia o form para o upload.php sem recarregar a página para o usuário. e retorna uma mensagem de sucesso ou erro.